# Retrieving cordova plugin information

Tags: javascript, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

I'm creating a(n) cordova customer plugin. Now I'm in the process of automating things so my question is after every successful install of a(n) plugin is there a way to instruct cordova to retrieve the plugin id and the clobbers target and put it in a JSON object or something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a json file for each platform in the /plugins folder.

If you need to generate an other file after a plugin is added, you can create a cordova hook in /hooks/after_plugin_add.

check those links about hooks:
http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/1197
https://github.com/apache/cordova-cli/blob/master/templates/hooks-README.md
http://devgirl.org/2013/11/12/three-hooks-your-cordovaphonegap-project-needs/